# onSectionRendered in react-window

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

In react-virtualized, there is a prop called "onSectionRendered" to define a function
which will be called after cells have been rendered.

What way is there to achieve this with react-window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found react-window's method onItemsRendered which does exactly the same as onSectionRendered.